# How can I change the Pycharm interpreter to 3.7 in Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: python, pycharm, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed python3.7.3 on Ubuntu14.04.

I want to change the interpreter of Pycharm. However, it is not supported.

This is the error:

[image: picture showing it's not supported]

> [unsupported] python 3.7/usr/bin/python3

How can I make it supported?

Comment: A good time to update your IDE and the OS, isn't it?

Comment: wht not try [pycharm support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html)?

Comment: I am sorry to say that update my IDE and OS seems no help.

Comment: Yes, I cannot run anything even a hello world.

Comment: that seems a real problem.

Comment: I am using pycharm-community-2019.1.3

Comment: is the exe available in bin? i think the path is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

check the path again, the exe path. mine is working perfectly well, i am not using ubuntu.

typing python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)" will give you correct path

you have to write /usr/local/bin/python3 instead of /usr/bin/python3

Comment: how to check the path?

Comment: python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"

Comment: the path is /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: it is not the same as the picture I posted, should I add a path as /usr/bin/python3  since it is in my picture?

Comment: you have to write /usr/local/bin/python3    instead of /usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 0):

Try using Anaconda to create a Python environment from PyCharm. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html for instructions.

Anaconda environments are generally easier to work with than system-wide Python installations, since some projects may require conflicting versions of packages or different Python versions.